# Best distance metric and estadarization method for clustering with percentages data

Tags: clustering, feature-scaling, distance

I'm studying access patterns to a facility with clustering.

My variables are percentages. For example, for each user, I have the percentage of access 'in time' versus late, or the percentage of using a particular door access by weekday (percentage of accesses on Monday, Tuesday...).

Which would be a good distance metric for clustering? Is Euclidean distance good?

Also, for previous scaling, Which method is best?,Mean/deviation, min/max (0-1), any others you would recommend?

Finally, if I have a few other variables (just a couple among dozens of percentages) that are counts (number of accesses), should I consider another distance/scaling method?